# Convert touch location of UITapGestureRecognizer for SpriteKit - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, touch, scenekit, uitapgesturerecognizer

I created a game with a `SceneKit scene` into a `UIViewController`.

I implemented a `UITapGestureRecognizer` like this :

```
// TAP GESTURE

let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
sceneView.overlaySKScene?.view!.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

And the `handleTap` function :

```
func handleTap(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

        var touchLocation = sender.locationInView(sender.view)

        touchLocation = self.view.convertPoint(touchLocation, toView: self.view)

        let touchedNode = sceneView.overlaySKScene?.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

        if touchedNode == myNode {

            // DO SOMETHING

        }

    }

}
```

Imagine that `myNode`'s position is `(x: 150.0, y: 150.0)`.
The problem is that the `touchPosition.y` is at the opposite of the y position of `myNode`'s y position.

How can I invert y position of the touch ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this instead, its accurate for me:-

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

     let tap:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tap:"))
     tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

     view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func tap(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){

    if sender.state == .Ended {

        var touchLocation: CGPoint = sender.locationInView(sender.view)
        touchLocation = self.convertPointFromView(touchLocation)

    }   
}
```

Comment: Where is the implementation of convertPointFromView ?

Comment: this override didMovetoView method is not call in My UIviewcontroller class. why?

Comment: one line
`let touchLocation = sender.locationInView(self)`